# HTML Download code will not let me download

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click on the w3schools logo to download the image:<p>

<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>



<img src="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" alt="W3Schools" width="104" height="142">



</a>


</body>



</html>
```

Comment: i test that code in www.w3schools.com and work fine to me

Comment: when i use it for audio download it goes straight to the music and it won't download. help uh brother out.

Comment: if that is your question edit this one and put the code that is don t working for you pls :D

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click on the w3schools logo to download the image:<p>

<a href="Ensumble.mp3" download>
  


<img src="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" alt="W3Schools" width="104" height="142">



</a>


</body>
</html>

Comment: don t put your code here edit your post to show the error

Comment: another thing, to download a file you have to give all the direction where you have the file if you only put the name of your file nothing will happend, and another thing if you want to use w3schools to test if you can download some of your own file that will not work because you don t have access to his files only to his code

Comment: When I write the code I change it to the appropriate code but when I run it. And click on the download it starts playing the music instead of downloading.

Comment: ok i understand you problem but pls put the right code in the post not the example of w3schools because i can t help you with that

Comment: I got you Im at work I'ma do it latter appreciate big hommie

Answer (score 0):

ok i gonna try to explain you this with a example, try to the following:

first create a folder in your desktop with the name "TestFolder" then create one folder with the name "images" and create a html file:(if you are in the good way you will have something like this)

[image]

then in your html file write the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click on the w3schools logo to download the image:<p>

<a href="../TestFolder/images/soundfile.mp3" download>
  <img src="../TestFolder/images/imagefile.jpg" alt="W3Schools" width="104" height="142">
</a>


</body>
</html>
```

then in your images folder put a image and replace the word imagefile of the html with the name of your image and do the same for the mp3 file(put a mp3 file in the image folder and then copy the name of the file in the word soundfile of the html file)

[image]

then open the html file with your browser (second click on the html file "open with" example: firefox) and you will have what you wanted
(even after all this I'm still unsure if this is what you wanted to do )

Comment: I tried it it still wouldn't let me download, any more ideas.

Comment: i can t help you more if you don t edit your post to know what are you doing wrong

Comment: I saved my MP3 file check me out in the Image foolder, and I created the html file in the image folder and here is my code. <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click on the w3schools logo to download the image:<p>

<a href="../TestFolder/images/Checkmeout.mp3" download="checkmeout">
  <img src="../TestFolder/images/imagefile.jpg" alt="W3Schools" width="104" height="142">
</a>


</body>
</html>

Comment: the html file you have to put it out of the folder of the images, you have to put it in the TestFolder

Comment: I been at work I'm going to try it when i get home. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Is it something I should download

Comment: you should edit this post with what you have doing, so if you don t do i cant help you more,because i cant see if all you are doing if the same that i am doing, and also if you don t edit the other users will not help you because they will not understand what you have done. sorry men

Comment: for some reason I can't get my screen shot of my folder wouldn't post, but I have the Mp3 and the HTML file in the same folder and here is my code                                                     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>

 

<a href="Check me out.mp3" Download="MKKIMK">Download</a>
  <a href="/myfiles.zip">Download</a>

</body>
</html>

Comment: which browser are you using to open the html? i recommend you use firefox

Comment: , and i will not respond to you more while you don t change your post sorry

Comment: Mrpepo877 your A genius, it worked in Internet Explorer but won't work in Chrome why is that?